# Angular conflict with NgRoute and data-ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I´trying to implement the behance Api into my angular App, I use this code and it works.

```
var RoutingApp = angular.module('RoutingApp', ['ngRoute'])



RoutingApp.factory('behFactory', function($http) {  
var factory = {      
async: function(page) {
  var user = 'enokmadrid';
  var apiKey = 'wXg9JwtvGepF60zwE9f0t20YN4TGKxYc';
  var url = 'http://behance.net/v2/users/'+ user +'/projects?api_key='+ apiKey +'&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';     
    var promise = $http.jsonp(url).error(function (response, status) {
      alert(status);
    }).success(function (response, status) {
      console.log(response.projects);
    }).then(function (response, status) {
      return response.data;           
  });
  return promise;
}};


return factory;  
});
```

But my ng-route it´s not working since i used this to call angular.

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
```

If I call angular like this my ng-route works, but not my factory

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js" >
</script>
```

Something with the angular version, I´m really new on this,
thanks in advance!

Comment: `ngRoute` was built into `1.0.7` but was removed from core later. You can't switch those 2 versions without changing dependency and including or excluding `angular-route.js`. What isn't working in factory and what errors are thrown

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include angular-route.js
See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) and change your code like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```